# Ubuntu apt-get unable to fetch packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, aptitude

Just installed Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy) and anything I try to install via `sudo apt-get install` is failing and throwing a series of `404` erros.

Example - installing `tmux`

```
[jeeves@HAL] hadoop > sudo apt-get install tmux
[sudo] password for jeeves: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tmux
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 247 kB of archives.
After this operation, 577 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  tmux
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main tmux amd64 1.8-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tmux/tmux_1.8-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

In this case it can't fetch an archive URL.

I get something similar when installing `mysql-server`

```
....
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdbi-perl/libdbi-perl_1.627-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
....
```

... and numerous other packages.

I even tried `sudo apt-get update` and running with `--fix-missing?`

Is the Ubuntu repository just down (which seems odd given how many people rely on it) or did I miss something?

**EDIT:** Here's what happens when I try `sudo apt-get update`. The update itself doesn't work because of resources that can't be found

```
> sudo apt-get update
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease                                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease           
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/contrib amd64 Packages   
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/non-free amd64 Packages  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                       
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/contrib i386 Packages    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg                                       
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/non-free i386 Packages                               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg                                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease                                          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release                           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release                                      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg                                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources/DiffIndex        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Sources/DiffIndex 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Sources/DiffIndex  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Sources/DiffIndex    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/contrib Translation-en   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/non-free Translation-en  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Probably your index is out of date, so you are attempting to fetch resources which are no longer there. Retry after doing an `apt-get update`

Comment: Not programming-related; nominating for migration to https://superuser.com/ (where however it's bound to be a duplicate).

Comment: I gave `sudo apt-get update` a shot and it's failing for missing resources. See above output in the `EDIT`. Thanks!

Comment: I've re-hosted the question on the `Ask Ubuntu` forum: http://askubuntu.com/questions/625484/ubuntu-apt-get-unable-to-fetch-packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile fails to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842415/dockerfile-fails-to-build)

Comment: In my case, running the following command resolved the issue.

sudo apt --fix-broken install

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue.

This is linked to using a non LTS version of Ubuntu called an "End of life version". As those have discontinued support. You can check if your Ubuntu is at the end of life version on [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

The simplest solution is to do the following two steps:

1. Backup your sources list
   `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`
2. Open the sources file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and rename all the instances of **us.archive** or **archive** in

   - http://**us.archive**.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
   - to
   - http://**old-releases**.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
   - Also do the same for the http://**security**.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages
3. Run `sudo apt-get update` after doing the above.

That should fix the issue.

**Security warning**: Please update your Ubuntu to an LTS version (to find the current one look into the docs [here](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)) as soon as possible, otherwise you won't be getting the latest security patches. The workaround presented in this answer is definitely not a solution that you would deploy on production machines.

**Non-US**: localized versions may use a different variant (e.g., search for **fr**.archive.ubuntu.com instead of **us**.archive.ubuntu.com - change "fr" based on your locale)

Comment: I'm assuming there's a security concern with doing this, and if there is, perhaps this answer should be revised with a big warning (i.e., "NOTE: end of life versions no longer receive security updates. If you do this, don't think you're getting the latest software!!"). Thanks!

Comment: How should this work? Now I am getting: `W: Failed to fetch http://old-security.ubuntu`

Comment: `Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.154 90]`

Comment: tip: for pt.1 just shortcut: `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.backup}` to do the same

Answer (score 48):

I tried using :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and then use :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that you will be able to install any packages.

If this did not worked for you try to change the network conf in `apt.conf`

Comment: I got a `E: Invalid operation do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @SouradeepNanda try the second step `sudo apt-get update`, and if issue still persist then try to search for the cause of the error you are getting. Check out other solutions as well.

Answer (score 38):

Just for the sake of any Googlers, if you're getting this error while building a Docker image, preface the failing RUN command with

```
apt-get update &&
```

This happens when Docker uses a cached image. Why the cached image *wouldn't* have the latest repo information the second time around is totally beyond me, but prefacing every single apt-get with an update does solve the problem.

Comment: The cached image may have outdated package info. Run your docker build with `--no-cache` instead.

Answer (score 17):

I have been fighting the same thing for a while.

after all the research, this is the best solution.....

**add the following to your resolve.conf file   /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4**

https://serverfault.com/questions/717226/ubuntu14-04-unable-to-apt-get-update/771826#771826

Answer (score 8):

In my case it failed to fetch be.archives.ubuntu.com (Belgium) so I generated a new sources.plist on [this link](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) as recommended by the accepted answer.

The thing that solved it for me was just to change the country to *United States* when generating the sources.plist. Then I could run this again.

```
apt-get update
```

Comment: shouldn't be `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I had the same problem after moving to a new country. A simpler way to do the same thing is to open the settings, software & updates. Then change the "Download from" option to another server.

Answer (score 7):

For simplicity sake here is what I did.

```
cd /etc/apt
mkdir test
cp sources.lst test
cd test
sed -i -- 's/us.archive/old-releases/g' *
sed -i -- 's/security/old-releases/g' *
cp sources.lst ../
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4):

Ran into issues like, while running `sudo apt-get install python3-env` on Ubuntu WSL:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 python3.5-venv amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
```

Running

> sudo apt-get update

fixed those issues.

Answer (score 4):

If you're having the issue with VirtualBox and a Virtual Machine I fixed it by changing *Settings* -> *Network* -> *Attached To* from *NAT* to *Bridged Adapter*

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by the use of a proxy as well. 
Check if you have proxy definitions in the /etc/environment file:

`cat /etc/environment`

If you have anything with http_proxy or https_proxy upper or lower case then `unset` each of them.

Answer (score 3):

ON MAC: Nothing was helping until I realised ScreenTime was blocking the update website! Turning off content filtering fix it

Comment: WOW. You just saved me another few hours debugging this. And I only turned content blocking on for reddit!

Answer (score 2):

As Tariq Khan suggested, I did the same thing and it worked out..

**FIX UBUNTU 14.10 UNICORN APT-GET UPDATE**

Backup the repo first

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup 
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

rename us.archive or archive  in http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/    as  http://old-release.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

rename http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages   as  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo in these instructions... should be "rename us.archive or archive in http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ as http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"  , specifically, not old-release, but old-releases...

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue when the Virtualbox had the wrong networking. I've updated to NAT and was able to get on internet and download packages from us.archive.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

After trying all the suggestions given here and other threads like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298177/a-failed-to-fetch-error-occurs-when-apt-get-update-is-run-how-do-i-fix-this) I still couldn't get `apt_get` to work on my Vagrant Ubuntu 16.04. In the end removing the file `apt.conf` from `/etc/apt` resolved the issue for me. My remaining files in that directory are:

```
vagrant@default:~$ ls -l /etc/apt/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 15 12:20 apt.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 21  2019 auth.conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    53 Mar 19 19:50 preferences
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 14  2016 preferences.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3166 Sep 10 15:55 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 10 16:04 sources.list.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17640 Mar 19 20:04 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17281 Mar 19 20:01 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 10 13:45 trusted.gpg.d
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had an issue with apt-get update getting stuck at 0%;

> 0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]

Could be some sort of DNS issue on ipv6. I just add this as a workaround;

```
-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this really interesting solution today, which worked for me on an Ubuntu server. Some DNS or another issue in the `apt` was making it adamant to not installing some packages from a custom PPA. What I did was install the [apt-fast](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast) package and use it to install my packages instead of `apt`.

`apt-fast` is an alternative to `apt` which works on top of `apt` but uses `aria2c` to download packages. It is used to increase the download speed. In my case, it also solved whatever network problem was making `apt` to fail.

Using it is exactly the same as `apt`:

```
sudo apt-fast install package-name
```