# Unmet dependencies stops Rednotebook from installing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Rednotebook on my Ubuntu 16.04. But [this](https://asciinema.org/a/bncrepdm7uubciw5ouahf2btm) is the error I get while installing.

I had it running nicely but I uninstalled and purged it for no reason and then tried to reinstall.
Have searched many solutions for unmet dependencies but none of the solution worked. Is that because I have Anaconda installed and its preventing other applications to use the packages installed under it?

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD309.png) is the error screenshot.

Comment: so i love the gif, but please add some error output here so it's easier for others to search for your issue/solution

Comment: maybe http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30843486/6085135

Comment: provide your error screenshot.

Comment: I updated the question with error screenshot. Thanks.