# graphviz install fails with libtiff5_4.0.6-1ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb 404 Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, graphviz, libtiff

I tried `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install graphviz`. But it failed with 404 Not found for `libtiff5`.

So I tried installing `libtiff5` separately

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libtiff5
```

gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjbig0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjbig0 libtiff5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 175 kB of archives.
After this operation, 615 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libjbig0 amd64 2.1-3.1 [26.6 kB]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Fetched 26.6 kB in 0s (250 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.0.6-1ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libtiff5 --fix-missing
```

But the same error gets thrown. Looks like I'm missing something silly, aren't I?

EDIT: This is not a problem with graphviz itself. In a fresh ubuntu docker, it installs fine. I'm trying to understand why it fails and fix its installation on my machine.

Comment: care to comment why you would want to close mr.anonymous?

Comment: possibly connected:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316812/ubuntu-apt-get-unable-to-fetch-packages

Comment: This looks a little bit tricky! I looked at the sources.list, nothing had `http://us.archive.ubu...` instead that was `http://archive.ubu...`.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Reset `/etc/apt/sources.list`

---

I downloaded an image from the official tensorflow docker [repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow) [docker://tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.1-gpu-py3-jupyter] and it is only roughly 2 months old (at the time of writing) and it was in this particular image I couldn't install graphviz. Digging further, it seems it wasn't just `libtiff5`, it was so many other things that apt wouldn't install. That confirms that the culprit wasn't `graphviz` but instead it is indeed the download sources.

I found a default sources.list [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1/raw/fcdfde2ab57e455ba9b37077abf85a81c504a4a9/sources.list) and since there was no way to **reset** the sources file to what it was in the beginning, I needed to `wget` or `git` to get that file from web (unless I want to put the whole sources.list in the docker file). But unfortunately, even `apt update && apt install git` or `apt update && apt install wget` failed with the 404 Error.

Finally I managed to get it working using a *temporary* solution:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/archive.ubuntu.com/http:\/\/us.archive.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Still, I couldn't find out why official US mirrors work while the parent ubuntu archive wouldn't. (Any answers explaining that are welcome.)

Related Links:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1031505
- https://askubuntu.com/q/65911