# ffmpeg install failing on docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ffmpeg, avconv

I have a Dockerfile as below, where i am trying to install ffmpeg for audio-video processing.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN  apt-get update  
RUN  apt install ffmpeg -y --fix-missing
```

I have tried other versions of Ubuntu docker image as well, but i keep getting the error as

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/slang2/libslang2_2.3.1a-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors4_3.4.0-4_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

Where if i use the Libav-tools as :

```
RUN apt-get install libav-tools -y
```

I get the error as I need to update to avconv version 10, which is not helping either.

Can anyone here help for how should I go about extracting audio from videos on docker container ?

Comment: ffmpeg has many dependencies and requirements. It would probably be easier for you to use an already made ffmpeg image, like [jrottenberg/ffmpeg](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg)

Comment: @Sarang I've successfully ran your dockerfile, you should be online/connected to the internet while building the image.

Comment: @RafafTahsin i'm surely connected to the internet, able to download all other dependencies. maybe the specific addresses are not accessible from my location ? Is that possible

Comment: @sarang will you try removing all existing docker images and try to run again ? I see no error other than connection problem. Also you can download this image which I've build from your Dockerfile - https://cloud.docker.com/u/rafaftahsin/repository/docker/rafaftahsin/ffmpeg-ubuntu

Comment: @RafafTahsin, i would love to use this image, but the image is unaccessible from my end, dont know for what reason.

Comment: trying pulling with `docker pull rafaftahsin/ffmpeg-ubuntu:18.04`

Comment: @Sarang and run as `docker run -it rafaftahsin/ffmpeg-ubuntu:18.04`

Answer (score 0):

Well as mentioned in the comments from @Sarang the image you are trying to build should work fine 
I can suggest few solutions:

- Start small sever and build the image and then push it to docker hub if you don't wanna to use your own image
- you can change the the Repos and try again

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue changing this

```
RUN  apt-get install 'ffmpeg'
```

to

```
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install 'ffmpeg'
```

And then rebuilding the image with no-cache.

It seems to be a problem with the cached image of docker, according to [Phil Kulak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616001/8815980)