# How to correctly build a project with i386 dependency?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x86, arm

I am trying to put this `https://github.com/zhelnio/schoolRISCV` on vm Linux primary2 5.4.0-113-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 14:34:18 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux.

There is a line like this in the makefile:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

I end up with a similar thing:
`E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]`

I read the article from here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316812/ubuntu-apt-get-unable-to-fetch-packages` , but it didn't help as I don't see anything like this `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`